# How to search through array in Spring Boot CrudRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql, jpa-criteria

Say, I have the following entity class:

**Person.java**

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  private String name;

  private String[] cars;

  // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

And the repository:

**PersonRepository.java**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {

   // this is unclear!
   List<Person> getAllByCars...(String car)
}
```

Is there a method that returns all persons, whose car array contains one given car (the String parameter above)?

For me, it seems that all supported JPA keywords can only deal with single elements, but not with arrays.

Thanks for help!

Comment: should not cars be another entity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, You should declare cars as a separate Entity like this

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  private String name;

  private List<Car> cars;

  // Constructor, getters and setters
}
```

If not you should change Array to List at the least.
change

```
private String[] cars;
```

to

```
@ElementCollection
private List<String> cars;
```

Then You have to write a Query like this

```
@Query("select p from Person p WHERE :car in elements(p.cars)")
List<Person> getAllByCars...(@Param("car") String car)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your suggested query did the trick. Since I'm using only a list of Strings in this example, I don't see a reason to implement a separate entity for that

Comment: b.t.w. I had to annotate cars with @ElementCollection in order to make it work

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that. Updated the answer

Comment: After changing String[] to List<String>, you could just define a method in your CrudRepository like this and that would do the job ---- List<Person> findAllByCars(String car)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at how you are currently storing the cars information and suggesting a possible solution:

```
@Entity
public class Car {
  @Id
  private String name;

  @Column
  private String person_name;
}

public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
    //Result will have all cars with the person_name identifying the Person @Entity
    List<Car> findByName(String name);
}
```