# how to construct spring JPA/JPQL query in JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I've got a DB structure like this:

```
topics 1:n posts  1:n comments and users n:n roles.
```

I want to get all comments that user have an access.

Giving access for me means (when I create post object I automaticly create role object called PostName with prefix role_comment_ e.g. post called abc have role called: role_comment_abc)

Now I try to create jpa/jpql query like below:

```
find all comments by User where user_id is =:1 and role_name contaings =:2
findByUserIdAndRoleNameContaining(Integer userId, String roleName);
```

This is how my User, Role and comment tables looks like:

Roles table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

Users and user_role tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
private Integer id;
private String name;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(
        name = "user_role",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") }
)
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

And this is comments table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comments{

@Id
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String description;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "user_id")
private User user
```

Unfortunetly if I create query in JpaRepository called:

```
List<Comments> findByUserId(Integer id);
```

If i'm not wrong it will print comments created by that specific user.

So what I really want to achive? Let me show you this on example data:

roles:

```
100;"role_comment_ab"
101;"role_comment_cd"
102;"role_comment_ef"
103;"something_else"
```

Comments in post with name ab:

```
1;"Test1";"Test description";10
2;"Test2";"Test description";10
```

comments in post with name cd:

```
3;"Test3";"Test description";10
4;"Test4";"Test description";10
```

comments in post with name ef:

```
5;"Test5";"Test description";10
6;"Test6";"Test description";10
```

users:

```
10;"Thomas" (logged user)
11;"John"
```

users_roles:

```
10;100
11;101
10;102
10;103
```

input:

```
findByUserIdAndRoleNameContaining(10, "role_comment_");
```

output:

```
   1;"Test1";"Test description";10
   2;"Test2";"Test description";10
   5;"Test5";"Test description";10
   6;"Test6";"Test description";10
```

I'm really out of clue how my query should look like. Pleast atleast give me a small hint.

UPDATE:
After adding @Bohdan Petrenko solution:

```
@Query("select c from Comment c join c.user u join u.roles r where u.id = :userId and lower(r.name) like lower(:roleName)")
List<Comment>  findByUserIdAndRoleNameContaining(@Param("userId") Integer userId, @Param("roleName") String roleName);

roleName = "%" + roleName.trim() + "%";
```

I noticed that this solution prints all comments if @Param roleName contains "roleName" String.

So if I have role_postName1 and role_postName2
it prints:

```
comment1FromPost1
comment2FromPost1
comment1FromPost2
comment2FromPost2
comment1FromPost1
comment2FromPost1
comment1FromPost2
comment2FromPost2
```

It would've be great to find solution to print comments from posts only if user have role called role_postName.

Comment: did you try `findByUser_IdAndUser_Roles_Name(Integer userId, String roleName)`

Comment: Your solution gave me an error: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [null.user.roles] of basic type

Comment: @pvpkiran do you have any idea why this problem goes out?

Comment: since roles is a set. I think you need to use elements and see if the role is there in the set of roles for that user. Check out my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424575/how-to-search-through-array-in-spring-boot-crudrepository/48425205#48425205

Answer (score 1):

```
@Query("select t from Topic t 
        join t.user u 
        where u.id = :userId 
        and u.roles in :roleNames")
List<Topic>  findByUserIdAndRoleNameContainedIn(@Param("userId") Integer userId, @Param("roleNames") List<String> roleNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific in your questions.

If I understood you correctly - You want to select Topics by user id and Role name. If yes you may try something like this:

```
@Query("select t from Topic t join t.user u join u.roles r where u.id = :userId and lower(r.name) like lower(:roleName)")
List<Topic>  findByUserIdAndRoleNameContaining(@Param("userId") Integer userId, @Param("roleName") roleName);
```

But you'll also need to change role name before passing it to the repository method `findByUserIdAndRoleNameContaining`:

```
roleName = "%" + roleName.trim() + "%";
```

**UPDATE**

This will work without any custom SQL and `roleName` modifications

```
List<Comment> findByUser_IdAndUser_Roles_NameContainingIgnoreCase(Integer userId, String roleName);
```

And also I don't understand the trouble you are faced with now. So, provide us some examples with a test data (from the data base), correct and incorrect expected results of the query. As I don't understand the reason of your problem I can't help you to solve it.

Comment: Sorry, I made a small misstake in a question. 
I want to select Comments (not Topics), but it will be a similar thing. :)
Just give me a second to check your solution :)

Comment: Yes, sure. No problem. But take a look at @pvpkiran 's answer. It's shorter and cleaner.

Comment: Something isn't right in your solution.  (it's probaly because of missunderstanding my question).
Let me update my question for you.

Comment: What I want to do is: get all comments from posts only if user have role called role_postName. But User can have even 10 roles.

Comment: So, you don't want to specify user id at all? Role name only? Or you want to make user id optional and specify only if it's present?

Comment: Yeah, I want to specify user id. But this one works properly so I didnt mention that.

Comment: e.g. user with id 100 have role with id 10,11,12 (role_a, role_b, role_c). This means I want to get all comments from post a, b and c. if I'm logged as user with id 100.